# Puzzle: JS Function that returns itself until there are no arguments

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve a puzzle, and am at my wit's end trying to figure it out.

I'm supposed to make a function that works like this:

```
add(1);       //returns 1
add(1)(1);    //returns 2
add(1)(1)(1); //returns 3
```

I know it can be done because other people have successfully completed the puzzle.  I have tried several different ways to do it.  This is my most recent attempt:

```
function add(n) {
    //Return new add(n) on first call
    if (!(this instanceof add)) {
        return new add(n);   
    }

    //Define calc function
    var obj = this;
    obj.calc = function(n) {
        if (typeof n != "undefined") {
            obj.sum += n;
            return obj.calc;            
        }

        return obj.sum;
    }

    //Constructor initializes sum and returns calc(n)
    obj.sum = 0;
    return obj.calc(n);
}
```

The idea is that on the first call, a new `add(n)` is initialized and `calc(n)` is run.  If `calc` receives a parameter, it adds `n` to `sum` and returns itself.  When it eventually doesn't receive a parameter, it returns the value of `sum`.

It makes sense in theory, but I can't get it to work.  Any ideas?

--edit--

My code is just the route I chose to go.  I'm not opposed to a different approach if anyone can think of one.

Comment: One way to handle it is to use [Object.prototype.valueOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf)

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to accomplish this (if it even works), is to override the `toString` (or `valueOf`) method of this function. Otherwise, there's no way to know when the function calling (currying) ends (without some terminator)

Answer (score 11):

To answer "how dow this work". Given:

```
function add(n) {
    function calc(x) {
        return add(n + x);
    }
    calc.valueOf = function() {
        return n;   
    }
    return calc;
}

var sum = add(1)(2)(3); // 6
```

When *add* is called the first time, it stores the value passed in in a variable called *n*. It then returns the function *calc*, which has a closure to *n* and a special *valueOf* method (explained later).

This function is then called with a value of 2, so it calls *add* with the sum of `n + x`, wich is `1 + 2` which 3.

So a new version of *calc* is returned, this time with a closure to *n* with a value of 3.

This new *calc* is called with a value of 3, so it calls *add* with `n + x`, which this time is `3 + 3` which is 6

Again *add* returns a new *calc* with *n* set to 6. This last time, *calc* isn't called again. The returned value is assigned to the variable *sum*. All of the *calc* functions have a special *valueOf* method that replaces the standard one provided by [*Object.prototype*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.4). Normally *valueOf* would just return the function object, but in this case it will return the value of *n*.

Now *sum* can be used in expressions, and if its *valueOf* method is called it will return 6 (i.e. the value of *n* held in a closure).

This seems pretty cool, and *sum* will act a lot like a primitve number, but it's actually a function:

```
typeof sum == 'function';
```

So be careful with being strict about testing the type of things:

```
sum * 2   // 12
sum == 6  // true

sum === 6 // false -- oops!!
```

Comment: Brilliant explanation! Thank you!

Comment: Much better than my own explanation :) .

Comment: Perhaps it could be even better if used prototypes.

Comment: @zerkms—perhaps, but while it's interesting, I wouldn't recommend it. The returned object only half behaves like a number, e.g. `add(1.1)(2.2).toFixed(2)` may disappoint. Its `[[Prototype]]` should be set to *Number.prototype*. ES6 has *setPrototype* but advises against using it.

Comment: Does this technique work anymore?  I'm seeing no success on latest Chrome or Node.  It ignores the valueOf and returns the function.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a somewhat streamlined version of @RobG's great answer:

```
function add(n) { 
    function calc(x) { return n+=x, calc; }
    calc.valueOf = function() { return n; };
    return calc;
}
```

The minor difference is that here `calc` just updates `n` and then returns itself, rather than returning itself via another call to `add`, which puts another frame on the stack.

#### Making self-replication explicit

`calc` is thus a pure self-replicating function, returning itself. We can encapsulate the notion of "self replication" with the function

```
function self_replicate(fn) {
    return function x() {
        fn.apply(this, arguments);
        return x;
    };
}
```

Then `add` could be written in a possibly more self-documenting way as

```
function add(n) { 
    function update(x) { n += x; }
    var calc = self_replicate(update);
    calc.valueOf = function() { return n; };
    return calc;
}
```

#### Parallel to Array#reduce

Note that there is a certain parallelity between this approach to repeatedly calling a function and `Array#reduce`. Both are reducing a list of things to a single value. In the case of `Array#reduce` the list is an array; in our case the list is parameters on repeated calls. `Array#reduce` defines a standard signature for reducer functions, namely

```
function(prev, cur)
```

where `prev` is the "accumulator" (value so far), `cur` is the new value being fed in, and the return value becomes the new value the accumulator. It seems useful to rewrite our implementation to make use of a function with that kind of signature:

```
function add(n) { 
    function reducer(prev, cur) { return prev + cur; }
    function update(x) { n = reducer(n, x); }
    var calc = self_replicate(update);
    calc.valueOf = function() { return n; };
    return calc;
}
```

Now we can create a more general way to create self-replication-based reducers based on a reducer function:

```
function make_repeatedly_callable_function(reducer) {
    return function(n) { 
        function update(x) { n = reducer(n, x); }
        var calc = self_replicate(update);
        calc.valueOf = function() { return n; };
        return calc;
    };
}
```

Now we can create `add` as

```
var add = make_repeatedly_callable_function(function(prev, cur) { return prev + cur; });
add(1)(2);
```

Actually, `Array#reduce` calls the reducer function with third and fourth arguments, namely the index into the array and the array itself. The latter has no meaning here, but it's conceivable we might want something like the third argument to know what "iteration" we're on, which is easy enough to do by just keeping track using a variable `i`:

```
function reduce_by_calling_repeatedly(reducer) {
    var i = 0;
    return function(n) { 
        function update(x) { n = reducer( n, x, i++); }
        var calc = self_replicate(update);
        calc.valueOf = function() { return n; };
        return calc;
    };
}
```

#### Alternative approach: keeping track of values

There are certain advantages to keeping track of the intermediate parameters the function is being called with (using an array), and then doing the reduce at the end instead of as we go along. For instance, then we could do `Array#reduceRight` type things:

```
function reduce_right_by_calling_repeatedly(reducer, initialValue) {

    var array_proto = Array.prototype, 
        push = array_proto.push, 
        reduceRight = array_proto.reduceRight;

    return function(n) { 
        var stack=[],
            calc = self_replicate(push.bind(stack));

        calc.valueOf = reduceRight.bind(stack, reducer, initialValue);
        return calc(n);
    };
}
```

#### Non-primitive objects

Let's try using this approach to build ("extend") objects:

```
function extend_reducer(prev, cur) {
    for (i in cur) {
      prev[i] = cur[i];
    }
    return prev;
}

var extend = reduce_by_calling_repeatedly(extend_reducer);
extend({a: 1})({b: 2})
```

Unfortunately, this won't work because `Object#toValue` is invoked only when JS needs a primitive object. So in this case we need to call `toValue` explicitly:

```
extend({a: 1})({b: 2}).toValue()
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the tip on `valueOf()`.  This is what works:

```
function add(n) {
    var calc = function(x) {
        return add(n + x);
    }

    calc.valueOf = function() {
        return n;   
    }

    return calc;
}
```

--edit--

> Could you please explain how this works? Thanks!

I don't know if I know the correct vocabulary to describe exactly how it works, but I'll attempt to:

Example statement: `add(1)(1)`

When `add(1)` is called, a reference to `calc` is returned.

1. `calc` understands what `n` is because, in the "mind" of the interpreter, `calc` is a function child of `add`.  When `calc` looks for `n` and doesn't find it locally, it searches up the `scope chain` and finds `n`.
2. So when `calc(1)` is called, it returns `add(n + x)`.  Remember, `calc` knows what `n` is, and `x` is simply the current argument `(1)`.  The addition is actually done inside of `calc`, so it returns `add(2)` at this point, which in turn returns another reference to `calc`.

Step 2 can repeats every time we have another argument (i.e. `(x)`).

- When there aren't any arguments left, we are left with just a `definition` of `calc`.  The last `calc` is never actually called, because you need a `()` to call a function.  At this point, normally the interpreter would return a the function object of `calc`.  But since I overrode `calc.valueOf` it runs that function instead.
- When `calc.valueOf` runs, it finds the most recent instance of `n` in the scope chain, which is the cumulative value of all previous `n`'s.

I hope that made *some* sense.  I just saw @RobG 's explanation, which is admittedly much better than mine.  Read that one if you're confused.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
var add = function _add(a, b) {
    var boundAdd = _add.bind(null, a + b);

    boundAdd.valueOf = function() { 
        return a + b; 
    }

    return boundAdd;
}.bind(null, 0);
```

We're taking advantage of a feature of `bind` that lets us set default arguments on the function we're binding to. From the docs:

> bind() also accepts leading default arguments to provide to the target
>   function when the bound function is called.

So, `_add` acts as a sort of *master* function which takes two parameters `a` and `b`. It returns a new function `boundAdd` which is created by binding the original `_add` function's `a` parameter to `a + b`; it also has an overridden `valueOf` function which returns `a + b` *(the `valueOf` function was explained quite well in @RobG's answer)*.

To get the initial `add` function, we `bind` `_add`'s `a` parameter to `0`.

Then, when `add(1)` is called, `a = 0` (from our initial `bind` call) and `b = 1` (passed argument). It returns a new function where `a = 1` (bound to `a + b`).

If we then call that function with `(2)`, that will set `b = 2` and it'll return a new function where `a = 3`.

If we then call that function with `(3)`, that will set `b = 3` and it'll return a new function where `a = 6`.

And so on until `valueOf` is called, at which point it'll return `a + b`. Which, after `add(1)(2)(3)`, would be `3 + 3`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple approach and it meets the criteria the OP was looking for. Namely, the function is passed an integer, keeps track of that integer, and returns itself as a function. If a parameter is not passed - the function returns the sum of the integers passed to it.

```
let intArray = [];
function add(int){
    if(!int){
        return intArray.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr)
    }
    intArray.push(int)
    return add   
}
```

If you call this like so:

```
console.log(add(1)(1)());
```

it outputs 2.