# Javascript function executed in this pattern "xyz()()" throws error?

Tags: javascript, function

```
 var recursiveSum = function() {
    console.log(arguments.length);
 }
 recursiveSum(1)(2)(3);
```

Why is it throwing not a function error?
I am using NodeJs to execute above sript.

Comment: `recursiveSum` should return a function.

Comment: `although it a valid syntax?` because it isn't valid syntax

Comment: Well not all valid syntax does work. `undefined(2)` is valid syntax either (which actually is just what you're doing, considering the return value of `recursiveSum(1)`)

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832891/javascript-sum-function, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28927510/add-function-that-works-with-different-combinations-of-chaining-arguments, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25578728/puzzle-js-function-that-returns-itself-until-there-are-no-arguments,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18067040/1048572 to see how this is done correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would only work if `recursiveSum` would [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Return_values) a function.

Right now, you try to execute the return value of `recursiveSum(1)` as a function. It isn't (it's `undefined`), and thus an error is thrown; you try to execute `undefined(2)(3)`.

You could do something like this.

```js
function currySum(x) {
  return function(y) {
    return function(z) {
      return x + y + z;
    }
  }
}

console.log(currySum(1)(2)(3));
```

---

If you have a variable number of arguments and want to use this currying syntax, look at any of the questions [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45071925/962603#comment77116524_45071925): [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5832891), [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28927510), [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25578728) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18067040).

---

Alternatively, write an actual [variadic function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments):

```js
function sum() {
  var s = 0;
  for (let n of arguments) {
    s += n;
  }
  return s;
}

// summing multiple arguments
console.log(sum(1, 2, 3, 4));
// summing all numbers in an array
console.log(sum.apply(null, [1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

Comment: What if, I have 20 parameters

Comment: I have edited my answer to address that scenario, Sourabh.