# Sum function currying

Tags: javascript, currying

I'm trying to write a sum function that does the following:

`sum(1)(2)(3) => returns 6`

However, I am having hard time with my solution. I know i'm making a silly mistake, can someone point me in the right direction?

My Implementation:

```js
function add(args) {
  let sum = args[0];
  let func = function(...args2) {
    if (!args2[0]) return sum;
    sum += args2[0];
    return func;
  }
  return func;
}


add(1)(2)(3);
```

Additionally, can I write a generic function that does the following?
add(1)(2)(3) or add (1)(2)(3) () => 6

Comment: Is it supposed to take arbitrary numbers of arguments? You can’t have both `add(1)(2) === 3` and `add(1)(2)(3) === 6`, but `add(1)(2)() === 3` and `add(1)(2)(3)() === 6` is possible (and, I think, what your code already does, by trying to check for `undefined` with `if(!args2[0])` – although that won’t work for 0).

Comment: Try `const add = a => b => c => a + b + c;`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25578965/5648253

Comment: Currying is a novelty.  Just as you've had difficulty in constructing it, others will have a difficulty in maintaining it.  Best advice is to stay away from it if you can.

Answer (score 5):

To have an arbitrary amount of calls, all which take a number, you'd need the return value to behave both as a function *and* a number depending. So that:

```
const five = add(2)(3);
console.log(five(10)); // behaves like a function
console.log(five + 10); // behaves like a number
```

I can't think of anyway to do that (or if there's a good reason one *should* do that) other than what I'd call a hack.

---

---

With that said, for fun I was able to do the following by abusing `valueOf()`:

```js
const add = (num1) => {
  const func = (num2) => add(num1 + num2);
  func.valueOf = () => num1;

  return func;
}

console.log(add(1)(2)(3)); // *logs function* [output varies by environment]

console.log(add(1)(2)(3) + 10);  // 16
console.log(add(1)(2) + 10);  // 13
console.log(add(1) + 10);  // 11

console.log(add(1)(2)(3) == 6); // true
console.log(add(1)(2)(3) === 6); // false

console.log(typeof add(1)(2)(3)); // function
console.log(typeof (add(1)(2) + 3)); // number
```

But that's obviously not very kosher.

---

***Edit:*** Switched from using `toString()` to `valueOf()` per @PatrickRoberts's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52124406/sum-function-currying/52124734#comment91200676_52124734).

Comment: Why not use `valueOf` instead of `toString`?

Comment: Interesting you consider modifications of `toString` as abuse

Comment: @PatrickRoberts You're right; that would be better. (I think I would still call it hack-y though.)

Answer (score 1):

Recursion anyone?

```
function add(n) {
  return function(m) {
    if (isNaN(m)) return n;
    return add(n + m);
  };
}

// add(1)(2)(3)() => 6
// add(1)(2)(3)("")() => "6"
// add(1)("2")(3)() => "123"

// functional one liner
const add = n => m => isNaN(m) ? n : add(n + m);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you omitted the spread operator

```js
function add(...args) {
        let sum = args[0];
        let func = function(...args2) {
            if(args2[0] === undefined) return sum;
            sum += args2[0];
            return func;
        }
        return func;
    }
    
    
    console.log(add(1)(2)(3)());
```

cheers!!

Comment: But what if I want to do add(1)(2)(3) without a closing paranthesis?

Answer (score 0):

```
function sum(x){
   return function (y){
      return function(z){
        return x+y+z;
     }
   }
}
```

You can call like :
    sum(1)(2)(3)

Comment: the problem with your solution is it is not generic enough i.e i can't do this sum(3) 0r sum(3)(6)(1)(7)